# Automated hyperparmeter optimization in h2o flow ui

Tags: h2o

Is there a way to automate hyper-parameter optimization for models in `H2O`'s `Flow UI`, such as how python's scikit-learn package includes [GridGridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out how to use Grid Search in Flow [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#using-grid-search).  (Use CV in your grid search by setting `nfolds > 1`.)

H2O also supports Random (Grid) Search through the programmatic APIs, but it's not currently supported via Flow, so I created a [JIRA](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4717) for that.  More info on that at the [Grid Search](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html) section of the H2O User Guide.